# Correct way to transform a response into DTO

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, lombok

I have this response here and I'd like to parse it to clean some infos that come from my service. And I'd like to know if is there a better way to convert this response where has

```
"cnpj": {
    "numeroCNPJ": "string"
  },
```

a key and then inside another key, it will be nice to return directly "cnpj": "string" for example. I implemented it, but actually, I think there are better solutions for this problem.

Json from rest service:

```
{
  "cnpj": {
    "numeroCNPJ": "string"
  },
  "codigoCNES": {
    "codigo": "string"
  },
  "codigoUnidade": {
    "codigo": "string"
  },
 
  "diretor": {
    "cpf": {
      "numeroCPF": "string"
    },
    "nome": {
      "nome": "string"
    }
  },
  "nomeEmpresarial": {
    "nome": "string"
  },
  "nomeFantasia": {
    "nome": "string"
  }
}
```

The Json that I'd like to have:

```
{
        "cnpj": "string",
        "codigoCNES": "string",
        "codigoUnidade":  "string",

        "diretor": {
        "nome": "string",
        "numeroCPF": "string"
        },
        
        "nomeEmpresarial""string",
        "nomeFantasia": "string"
        
}
```

The DTO Class:

```
@Data
public class CNESDto {

    private String codigoCNES;
    private String codigoUnidade;
    private String nomeFantasia;
    private String nomeEmpresarial;
    private String cnpj;
    private DiretorDto diretor;

}
```

The way that I'm mapping it, I'd like to know if is there a clean way to implement it.

```
private CNESDto getCnesDto(DadosGeraisEstabelecimentoSaudeType response) {

    DiretorDto diretorDto = new DiretorDto();
    diretorDto.setName(response.getDiretor().getNome().getNome());
    diretorDto.setCpf(response.getDiretor().getCPF().getNumeroCPF());

    CNESDto cnesDto = new CNESDto();
    cnesDto.setCodigoCNES(response.getCodigoCNES().getCodigo());
    cnesDto.setCodigoUnidade(response.getCodigoUnidade().getCodigo());
    cnesDto.setNomeFantasia(response.getNomeFantasia().getNome());
    cnesDto.setNomeEmpresarial(response.getNomeEmpresarial().getNome());
    cnesDto.setCnpj(response.getCNPJ().getNumeroCNPJ());
    cnesDto.setEndereco(response.getEndereco());
    cnesDto.setDiretor(diretorDto);

    return cnesDto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"cnpj\": {" +
    "    \"numeroCNPJ\": \"string\"" +
    "  }," +
    "  \"codigoCNES\": {" +
    "    \"codigo\": \"string\"" +
    "  }," +
    "  \"codigoUnidade\": {" +
    "    \"codigo\": \"string\"" +
    "  }," +
    " " +
    "  \"diretor\": {" +
    "    \"cpf\": {" +
    "      \"numeroCPF\": \"string\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    \"nome\": {" +
    "      \"nome\": \"string\"" +
    "    }" +
    "  }," +
    "  \"nomeEmpresarial\": {" +
    "    \"nome\": \"string\"" +
    "  }," +
    "  \"nomeFantasia\": {" +
    "    \"nome\": \"string\"" +
    "  }" +
    "}");
    
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "entries().map(" +
    "    key::value.if([size()=1], *, **.mergeObjects())" +
    ")" +
    ".mergeObjects()");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "cnpj" : "string",
  "codigoCNES" : "string",
  "codigoUnidade" : "string",
  "diretor" : {
    "numeroCPF" : "string",
    "nome" : "string"
  },
  "nomeEmpresarial" : "string",
  "nomeFantasia" : "string"
}
```